# Bottom margin issue for edM in gmail

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, marketo

I'm creating a eDM newsletter as a template in Marketo and it views fine in nearly everything but gmail. Divs with images seem to be creating a bottom-margin or something and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. Please see mark up below and an image with red rectangles representing the problem margin areas.

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Responsive Template</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="bottom">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><div class="mktEditable" id="headerImage" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=25&txt=610%C3%97100&w=610&h=100" alt=""/></div></td>
                        <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="650"><div class="mktEditable" id="topBanner" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><img src="http://www.vision6.com.au/download/files/20677/2408194/Header.png" alt=""/></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="610" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div class="mktEditable" id="mainContent" style="padding: 20px; margin: 0px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis pharetra mi ut finibus. Sed elementum eros ut augue egestas eleifend. Quisque nibh neque.</div></td>
                        <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="610" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <div class="mktEditable" id="footerImage" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                            <img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=25&txt=610%C3%97100&w=610&h=100" alt=""/>  
                        </div></td>
                        <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
            body {
                width: 100% !important;
                min-width: 100% !important;
                }

            img {
                float: none !important;
                height: auto;
                max-width: 100%;
                margin: 0px !important;
                padding: 0px !important;
                }
</style>
</html>
```

IMG(gmail): http://s4.postimg.org/p2cwbvdn1/gmailmarginissue.jpg

edit*

IMG(No margin issue/Outlook): http://s16.postimg.org/yikdy0md1/Screen_Shot_2015_09_07_at_2_39_30_pm.png

Comment: hmmm, I don't see any issue on my browser, there's one banner image, and some texts beneath, where is the issue ?

Comment: Issue only seems to be in gmail, see screen shot at the botttom.

Comment: oh well, then it's pretty much hard to debug as a third person, can you email me one sample, so I can look it through the browser ?

Comment: Certainly! What's your email?

Comment: Can you add other domain sample screen shot, which is working fine.

Comment: Outlook screenshot added!

Comment: neophyte.polyhistor@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Gmail domain will not always support `div` tags, hence remove `div` tags and apply css to td and also make sure to give alignments to td's(ex: `<td align="left" valign="top"></td>`)

Comment: Adding this didn't seem to make any difference, and I can't remove the <div> tags because they reference editable fields.

Answer (score 0):

line-height was the issue. It was adding an extra 3px to the .